# Visual Studio 2017 Xamarin mapping of xaml Controll Object and sourcecode initialisation

Tags: xaml, xamarin, webview

i have this in MainPage.xaml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:maiwell_webview_app"
             x:Class="maiwell_webview_app.MainPage">

    <AbsoluteLayout>
        <WebView Source="http://www.maiwell.com/" 
        AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0.5, 0.5, 1, 1"
        AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All" x:Name="WebView1"/>
    </AbsoluteLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

how can i access this webview in source-code?

this is not working in MainActivity.cs

```
        var browser = new WebView();

        browser.Source = "http://xamarin.com";

        Content = browser;
```

Comment: Your XAML is from `Xamarin.Forms` but your code is `Xamarin.Android`-based, what are you trying to do?

Comment: i want to build a Android, iOS, Windows App...

Comment: You should start with one of Xamarin samples, here is one that uses WebView: https://developer.xamarin.com/samples/xamarin-forms/WorkingWithWebview/

Comment: Thank you, but the Webview of the Android Version is broken in Visual Studio 2017....

Comment: The Webview example isn't broken, but the nuget resources in visual studio haven't been updated at my PC